# how to use font awesome icons in HTML

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-awesome

hi I cant use font awesome icons and I don't know what is the problem
please explain to me how I can use font awesome icons in this version  . step by step
yes there is some topic like this but I couldn't figure out answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First you have to write this in the head

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css">
```

Then whenever you want to use a font awesome, Just copy its HTML code and paste it where you want it to be. for example:

```
<i class="fa-solid fa-c"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should add the required stylesheet.

## **If you are using Font Awasome 4:**

Add this stylesheet before your `body` tag.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

### **Where to use it:**

Use it inside `body` tag.

Eg: `<i class="fa fa-link"></i>`

If you are using other versions of **Font Awasome** view their docs, just search font awasome docs of the individual version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CDNs to link font-awesome, but the docs recommends to download and use kits. You can download it here: https://fontawesome.com/kits

For more details you should look into its Docs: https://fontawesome.com/docs

Answer (score 0):

What i did is to create font Awesome code kit. copy and paste element to HTML head tag

```html
<head>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2b9cdc1c9a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<span>
<i class="fa-brands fa-amazon-pay"></i>
<span>
```